# Is it good to go with Fabric Composer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

Am starting to learn and develop a fabric.
Am bit confused over, whether to start development with fabric Composer or to go with full end development as in fabric samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, it is better to go for fabric first to understand the blockchain, and how it works and to see all the components.
Composer is pretty easier, you can build applications, but you will not understand the details of blockchains, although the composer is deploying its output bna file on fabric.

Composer is just tool, not the framework itself.
I'm sure that composer is easy for you, and you will become productive much faster